# how to customize tool tip while mouse go over bars on Chart js bar chart

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

My plan is to develop a bar chart like shown below
[image]

I am developing this in a angular JS platform and using chart JS library for chart.

The problem is i cannot show the tool tip on mouse over of bar as shown in image. Chart JS allowing only to show x and y axis measurement as tool tip. Any one know how can i show some text in tool tip.Pleas help.

Controller code

```
 $scope.chartdata = {
        labels: barchartYaxis,
        datasets: [
            {
                //label:['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'],
                label: '',
                fillColor: 'rgba(235,163,94,0.5)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.8)',
                highlightFill: 'rgba(229,136,94,0.75)',
                highlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                data: barchartXaxis
            }
        ]
    };

    // Chart.js Options
    $scope.chartoptions = {
        responsive: true,
        scaleBeginAtZero: true,
        scaleShowGridLines: true,
        scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
        scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
        barShowStroke: true,
        barStrokeWidth: 2,
        barValueSpacing: 5,
        barDatasetSpacing: 1,
        showTooltips: true,
        tooltipEvents: ["mousemove", "touchstart", "touchmove"],
        tooltipFillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
        tooltipTemplate: "<%=label%>,<%=value%>"
        //tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%>"+getHtmlFromTopicName("<%=label%>")+"<%}%>"
        //$scope.userDetails = data.user_details;
    }
```

template file

```
<canvas tc-chartjs-bar chart-options="chartoptions" chart-data="chartdata" auto-legend></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with code(chart configuration etc.) that is not working. So we can know what exactly can be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I have a custom tooltip working on chart.js charts in an angular application using the angular-chart.js directive:

I created my scaffolded app using yeoman (yo angular) and I added the directive using

```
bower install angular-chart.js --save
```

I added it to the modules in app.js

```
angular.module('chartapp', ['chart.js'])
```

The markup for the chart is

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="data"
  labels="labels" legend="true" series="series"
  click="onClick">
</canvas>
```

And my controller has the following data for the chart:

```
angular.module('oauthClientApp')
    .controller('ChartCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.labels=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'];

        $scope.series=['Series A'];

        $scope.data = [[10, 20, 30, 20, 10]];

        $scope.onClick = function(points, evt) {
            console.log(points, evt);
        };
```

The customisations you can perform on the global Chart object are outlined [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration)

Specifically the tooltipTemplate I set was as follows:

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipTemplate = function(value) {
    if (value.label)  {
        return value.label + ":" + value.value;
    } else {
        return value.value;
    }
};
```

Which gets called each time the tooltip is generated.

If your chart has multiple series then you need to do the same for multiTooltipTemplate:

```
Chart.defaults.global.multiTooltipTemplate = function(value) {
    return 'The value is ' + value.value;
};
```

Which gets called for each series.

There are plenty of other customisations you can perform.

Aidan

Comment: The function is working since my tool tip text is much longer i tried to insert html tags among the text. But when tried this
return "<ol>"+value.label + ":" + value.value+"</ol>";

the tag itself is appearing in the tool tip. I also tried "\n" ,but new line is not appearing......